# What is the naming rules for public static final class identifier in java?

Tags: java, class, naming-conventions

Java Naming rules suggests which one to be used.
This

```
public static final class DatabaseTable
```

or, this

```
public static final class DATABASE_TABLE
```

Which one is correct?

Comment: First (camel cased) one is better and preferred way of naming a class.

Comment: the two declarations have different meaning. one is declaring a static, final, public *inner class* while the other one is declaring a *variable* of type `clas` [public,static,final]. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "incorrect" here, in the sense that the Java compiler or syntax of the language does not force you to use specific naming conventions.

If we look at the old [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) document, specifically [Chapter 9 - Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367), we see that classes should have CamelCaseNames:

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).

It doesn't matter if the class is a nested class (`static`) or if the class is `final`.

ALL_UPPERCASE_NAMES are for constants; `static final` *variables* (not classes).

Answer (score 5):

I think first one is appropriate. Any class name that may be final or whatever, it's name should be in **proper case without any space**. Proper case means first letter of each word should be in **Upper Case** and remember don't use any **UnderScore** in this case.

You should name in the second style if it is a **final variable**

Answer (score 1):

fields with `public static final` modifiers are used as "constants" in Java and should be written in capitals. So the correct (compilable) statement would be:

```
public static final Class DATABASE_TABLE = DatabaseTable.class;
```

---

In case you were looking for a classname, then the naming convention is as usual for classes: first letter is capital, the name in CamelCaseNotation.

```
public static final class DatabaseTable {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Though correct, I *think* most will prefer `Class<?>` over `Class` :\

Comment: `public static final class DATABASE_TABLE { public static final TEST_TABLE ="tbltest" }` this is right code?

Comment: This is confusing. I don't think Ankur Patel means to create a `Class` constant here; he just wants to know what the naming convention for nested `final` classes is.

Answer (score 0):

I would still use the first one as CAPS are generally meant for CONSTANT fields, not for final methods or final classes even if they are static.